# Insert WKB to POINT column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, gis, spatial, wkb

Having a hard time working out what do I need to do to insert this export from MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO cities VALUES ('Nameoftheciy',0x0000000001010000005C21ACC6129C48407AFF1F274CA65EC0);
```

I tried wrapping the value in single quotes or extracting the data as `POINT()` but it also returns an errors in PostgreSQL.

What is the right approach here?

Comment: tried this? `SELECT 
 ST_AsEWKT(
 replace('0x0000000001010000005C21ACC6129C48407AFF1F274CA65EC0','0x','\x')::bytea::geometry(point,4326));`

Comment: This one complains that `geometry type doesn't exist`

Comment: I will delete the answer for the time being, as it serves no purpose for your issue. Consider using a standard format like `wkt`, `geojson`, or `gml`. Some time ago a guy had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59447658/2275388) and WKT did solve the issue.

Comment: did you install the postgis extension?

Comment: I was told today that Postgis library is not and will not be enabled on my server :/